# getting click position from pcl_visualizer

Tags: pcl

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I wanted to get the coordinates where a user clicked inside the pcl_visualizer. Preferably, I would like to get the equation of the 3D line that corresponds to back-projection of the point  which was clicked.

Thanks,
Abhishek

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9789/getting-click-position-from-pcl_visualizer/) by [aa755](https://answers.ros.org/users/303/aa755/) on ROS Answers with karma: 61 on 2011-04-20

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [AHornung](https://answers.ros.org/users/141/ahornung/) on 2011-04-21**:
You would probably get the best answers for this on the PCL mailing list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Unfortunately you can't get the coordinate of a single point using pcd_viewer in pcl_visualization.

---

Originally posted by [kwc](https://answers.ros.org/users/11/kwc/) with karma: 12244 on 2011-06-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1